# Anyway to install both MAAS controller and computing node on a single node?

Tags: maas

I wanna build a small private cloud. However, the resources are limited. I don't want to waste a node just running the controller process. So is there anyway to install a computing node program on the MASS controller?

Answer (score 1):

I have a [doc](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~smoser/maas/maas-pkg-test/view/head:/maas-ephemeral-test-quantal.txt) for testing maas that demonstrates how to do this.  It doesn't make sense other than for testing, but it is generally functional.  The nodes are kvm, and you dont have ipmi support.